# How to ensure that title shows username on hovering an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make it so an **title attribute** displays the username (different tag),
while hovering over a picture?

```
<div class="profile">
    <img class="image" src="images/7.png" title="here - that it will show the tag value">
    <div class="names-row">
        <p class="name">User</p>
        <p class="tag">@username</p>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to show the username inside the `title=""` value? Why don't you inject it beforehand on the server? Do you use any server-side technology? Any templating engine? Have you tried to use JS and the `setAttribute()` method in JavaScript?

Comment: Read about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Answer (score 3):

You can easily show username on hovering an image by **title** attribute. we can call it tooltip also. In your example there is no data for the profile. So at first I take a data object for profile. Then just put the username to the **title** attribute.

Example:

```
const profileInfo = {
  username: "Tanjim Hasan",
  tag:      "profile",
  src:      "images/7.png"
}

<div class="profile">
    <img class="image" src={profileInfo.src} title={profileInfo.username}>
    <div class="names-row">
        <p class="name">{profileInfo.username}</p>
        <p class="tag">{profileInfo.tag}</p>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully It will help you. :)

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you have access to the server-side which generates it, then the solution is to add the `title` attribute to your `img` as well. Yet, since you have not specified any server-side technologies in your question tags, I will assume in this answer that you cannot take that option and you need to use Javascript for this purpose. Here's an example:

```js
for (let profile of document.getElementsByClassName("profile")) {
    profile.querySelector("img.image").title = profile.querySelector(".tag").innerText;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
    <img class="image" src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.of-rlOxjEVIV6srGE0dLTQHaEo?pid=ImgDet&rs=1" title="here - that it will show the tag value">
    <div class="names-row">
        <p class="name">User</p>
        <p class="tag">@username</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="profile">
    <img class="image" src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.aetZEH1Rp6Pknak9-7BCXwHaFj?pid=ImgDet&rs=1" title="here - that it will show the tag value">
    <div class="names-row">
        <p class="name">User2</p>
        <p class="tag">@username2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the snippet above I added two profiles to illustrate that the code will work even if there are several profiles on the same page.

Answer (score -1):

Use javascript :)

if you only use css,

1. mouse effect on parent layer
2. do something on child layer

like below css

```
.names-row:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```js
const imagebtn = document.querySelector('.image')

imagebtn.addEventListener('pointerover', () => {
    document.querySelector('.name').style.opacity = 1
    document.querySelector('.tag').style.opacity = 1
})
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tag {
    opacity: 0;
}

.name {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="profile">
        <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" title="here - that it will show the tag value">
        <div class="names-row">
            <p class="name">User</p>
            <p class="tag">@username</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: JavaScript is not necessary. Also this misses the question completely.